# Need help on expdp and impdp concept

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, dump, impdp, expdp

I have a multiple databases i.e (database1,database2) and i need to export a table from database1 to database2 . Here are the commands i tried

```
expdp hr/oracle@oracle tables=emp directory = ora dumpfile=emp.dmp
```

This command will export the the emp.dmp file to "ora" directory but i need to import this dump file to another database but the "ora" directory is not accessible to the database2 . Do we have any other method to export the database dump .

Comment: Where are the databases? Same or different server? Same instance or different instance? Windows or Linux? How did you define the Export directory? Please provide as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

So? Just copy a dumpfile to a location accessible to database2.

`ora` is not a directory, it is a directory object defined in the database, that serves as an "alias" to the real path in the filesystem.

[Overview of Oracle Data Pump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL100)

[File Allocation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL817)

> Data Pump is server-based rather than client-based, dump files, log files, and SQL files are accessed relative to server-based directory paths. Data Pump requires that directory paths be specified as directory objects. A directory object maps a name to a directory path on the file system.
>
> The following example shows a SQL statement that creates a directory
>   object named dpump_dir1 that is mapped to a directory located at
>   /usr/apps/datafiles.

```
SQL> CREATE DIRECTORY dpump_dir1 AS '/usr/apps/datafiles';
```

Or you can import the table directly from database1 to database2 through a database link.

[Using Network Link Import to Move Data](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL806)

> When the Import NETWORK_LINK parameter is used to specify a network
>   link for an import operation, SQL is directly used to move the data
>   using an INSERT SELECT statement. The SELECT clause retrieves the data
>   from the remote database over the network link. The INSERT clause uses
>   SQL to insert the data into the target database. There are no dump
>   files involved.